# does cocoapods build settings override all project target settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Hello im new to cocoapods and I just had a question, do all the cocoapods build settings override the build settings I have set for my project target ? (specifcally enable bitcode)

Answer (score 0):

Not all cocoapods build settings override the build settings you have set for your project target.
Some build setting in your project target can be inherited so it's like allowance to setup your project target build settings from other place. When you run `pod install` cocoapods does magic that creates a workspace containing your project and Pods.xcodeproject. To support relationship between them cocoapods injects some changes into your project target.

Comment: do you know if it has any effect if my Xcode project has "C++ Language Dialect" set to "C++11", but my cocoaspods settings has it set to "GNU++ 14" ?